# Trivial (?) Proof

Tags: real-numbers

Take, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ to be real numbers.
If $a>b$ and $c>b$ and $d>b$,
can we prove that TECHNICALLY, $a+c>d$, or $a+d>c$, or $c+d>a$.
Kind of a brain teaser but I am looking for some honest proof. Thanks.

Comment: The word "technically" adds nothing other than noise.

Comment: Technically, the assumption has nothing to do with the conclusion, and technically it is always satisfied for some $b$.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false: For example, take

$$a=c=d=-1$$
$$b=-10000$$

Comment: Perhaps limit the domain to natural numbers?

Comment: @Gil Then it is trivial: Add the largest two.

Comment: And the OP **explicitly** wrote "real numbers" ...+1

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Ah, I see your point.

Comment: @DonAntonio I know, I thought that if the domain were restricted then perhaps the conjecture could be proved.